# How do I access the Shadow of Colossus developer menu?

Tags: cheats, shadow-of-the-colossus

I finally got a hold of my old PS2 copy of the Shadow of the Colossus demo. Is it true that there is an old developer menu you can access?  If so, how do I do that?

Comment: I doubt you could turn the demo into the full game, but that's an interesting idea.

Comment: I believe the developer menu (or maybe console) only provided you with simple debugging tools.

Comment: For the curious, [here's a page about the demo](http://teamico.wikia.com/wiki/Shadow_of_the_Colossus/_Demo). Though there are various ways to go "out of bounds", it's clear that the rest of the content is very much unfinished, so there's no possibility of "unlocking" the demo into a full version.

Answer (score 3):

Shadow of the Colossus had two demo versions. I believe one was an early trade-show floor build, and hard to come by. The other, which is what you probably have, shipping on a demo disc from the Official Playstation Magazine (or some other publication of that era).

I don't believe either version had a developer menu (I've never heard of one). Most of the time, such menus were accessible via GameShark to Action Replay codes. But I don't recall every having come across a code to enable such a menu or any other sort of broad "developer" functionality.

Indeed, if you peruse the game's entry over at [The Cutting Room Floor](http://tcrf.net/Shadow_of_the_Colossus), you'll see that there's a fair bit of cut content, but no serious mention of a developer mode in either the main game or any of its known demo builds.

Comment: Reading the CRF pages in more depth, it sounds like I might have gotten my memory of the relative ages of the two demos mixed up, but I'm not sure.

Comment: CFH also notes SotC as "Game with debugging features", but notable lacks this annotation on the two demos.